# MIN/MAX aggregate function with STRING in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, nls-sort

I don't understand the way Oracle do the sorting of a string with MIN/MAX. I guess, that small letter(a, b, c) should be returned before the big one (A, B, C). That's why my expectation is to get as MIN - "bob" - small b is "smaller" than big "J". With MAX opposite of it.

I'm getting in Postgres and Sql Server correct result. Is it caused due to some collation/language/character set differences?

```
  DROP TABLE test;
  CREATE TABLE test (a INT, name VARCHAR2(10));
   INSERT INTO test(a, name) 
       VALUES (1, 'John')
            , (2, 'bob')
       ;
  COMMIT;
  
  
  SELECT MIN(name) -- return John instead of bob
       , MAX(name) -- return bob instead of John
   FROM test;
```

My Oracle 23c XE configuration:

```
SELECT *
  FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS;
```

[image]

Comment: Does the documentation for [NLS_SORT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/NLS_SORT.html) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do:

```sql
SELECT t.*, ASCII(SUBSTR(name, 1, 1)) FROM test t;
```

Then the output is:

| A | NAME | ASCII(SUBSTR(NAME,1,1)) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 74 |
| 2 | bob | 98 |

And you can see than the ASCII code for `J` is 74 and `b` is 98 so comparing the underlying byte-values then 74 < 98 so `J` < `b`.

If you have:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP = 'BINARY';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = 'BINARY';
SELECT MIN(name), MAX(name) FROM test;
```

Then the output is:

| MIN(NAME) | MAX(NAME) |
| --- | --- |
| John | bob |

and you are comparing the values as binary.

If you change to a linguistic comparison and set the sort to be case-insensitive:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP = 'LINGUISTIC';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = 'BINARY_CI';
SELECT MIN(name), MAX(name) FROM test;
```

Then the output is:

| MIN(NAME) | MAX(NAME) |
| --- | --- |
| bob | John |

And `b` < `J`.

---

If you do not want to change the default NLS settings then you can explicitly specify the sort order in the query:

```sql
SELECT MIN(name) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY NLSSORT(name, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI'))
         AS min,
       MAX(name) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY NLSSORT(name, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI'))
         AS max
FROM   test;
```

Which outputs:

| MIN | MAX |
| --- | --- |
| bob | John |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bcQ8KzpV)

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know how does it works in other RDBMS? Is it safe to change the default setting for these parameters?

Comment: @drk You will need to refer to the documentation for other RDBMS to check how they behave. If you change the session in Oracle then it will affect how strings are sorted for the rest of that session (but not any other sessions). If you only want it to affect that query then you will need to modify the query to change how it sorts within that query - I've added one possible example.